# Display dates between a start and finish date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Ok this one has me stumped and not sure if it is even possible.  I have a database with a start and end date.  for example start date 2002 and end date 2012, however what i want to do is list all of the dates between these two points so for example, 2003, 2004, 2005, etc.

However these dates are not in the database, and so what i want to do is automatically create them.  Is this possible?, my other idea is to create a second database with a join and a list all the of dates.

Just after some advice really on what would be the best way to approach this.

Thanks

Comment: Why not do the date logic in your code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Such things should be done with PHP.

Use a couple of the many datefunctions PHP has to offer.
You can create a timestamp with `mktime()` and then use `strtotime()` for example to loop.

```
$start = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2002);
$end = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2012);

$currentDate = $start;
while($currentDate < $end) {
    echo date("Y", $currentDate) . "<br />";

    $currentDate = strtotime("+1 year", $currentDate);
}
```

Haven't tested it, but should work.

[strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

[mktime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

[List of all date functions in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php)

Answer (score 0):

your sql will look like that

```
  $query = "SELECT starttime st ,endtime et FROM your_table WHERE id = your_user_id_variable ";
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
```

and then use this php code

```
   for($i=1 , $i<$row['et'],$i++){
      echo $row['st']+$i.", " ;
            }
```

then it will echo 2003,2004,.....,2011

Answer (score -2):

you have to use between function

```
SELECT * FROM Persons
WHERE LastName
BETWEEN (2003 AND 2004);
```

Comment: Read the question carefully: 'However these dates are not in the database, and so what i want to do is automatically create them'

Comment: The answer is not related to the question